# Multiple developers workflow with shared terraform codebase

Tags: terraform, devops

I am newbie working on the team which does a lot of TF code as part of the development. The TF state is stored in remote S3 bucket. While finishing my work in my own branch I realized my TF objects deployed from my branch

```
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "b" {
  bucket = "my-tf-test-bucket"
  acl    = "private"

  tags = {
    Name        = "My bucket"
    Environment = "Dev"
  }
}
```

will be deleted by another developer because he uses his own branch which doesn't have this object in it. Indeed when he run his terraform apply he got this:

```
$ terraform apply -target=module.s3
aws_s3_bucket.b: Refreshing state... (ID: my-tf-test-bucket)

An execution plan has been generated and is shown below.
Resource actions are indicated with the following symbols:
  - destroy
Terraform will perform the following actions:
  - module.s3.aws_s3_bucket.b
Plan: 0 to add, 0 to change, 1 to destroy.
```

How this type of work has to be structured from best practices point of view?
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure I understand what the problem is... So he either uses his own environment for his local changes, or merge to master first and resolve conflicts to deploy to shared environment. What else could be done here? What exactly is the problem, you are trying to solve?

Comment: You should manage resources within your folders. Each folder is a workspace root. That ways, each developer impacts only their own folders and not others.

Answer (score 0):

A strategy we used to follow was
1. Name the s3 bucket backend with the project and the region in which the resources are deployed
2. Divide the regions among the devs that are working simultaneously

That way the tfstate gets stored in different buckets per developer. Of course, there has to be a verbal agreement between the devs to successfully do this. If the team is too large for that I guess what you can do is to include the user id in the backend bucket name as well.

Answer (score 0):

We have different development environments that are spun up for each developer (we have two currently).  To do this, often we will prefix resources with some identifier (a variable that is set via the command line that is picked up in the terraform main file) so that there isn't a collision between different environments that are in the same account.  Once changes are approved, it moves to our CI environment which only deploys changes that make it past dev (changes are automated by the pipeline and never done by a dev). You shouldn't be sharing a shared state like that on a development environment as you'll often get the problem you're facing.

I'm not necessarily sure if this is ***best practice*** or not, but it works well for us.